# Start another activity (by Intent) on half screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to start an activity (ie. Calculator) from within my main activity but in such a way that it only takes a part of the screen and not the whole screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do that before [honeycomb fragments](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2448-how-to-use-the-fragment-class-in-the-android-honeycomb-sdk-preview/).

But nothing prevents you from taking your calculator apart, and make it a reusable view.

Comment: Fragments are exactly what I was looking for, thanks. BTW, Android came out with a library that allows you to use fragments as early as [Android 1.6](Fragments are exactly what I was looking for, thanks. BTW, Android came out with a library to allows you to fragments as early as Android 1.6. [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)

Comment: Yea, but watch out for the pitfalls of the support library, some of the functions are not implemented correctly. Make sure you test on old devices and don't assume things will just work magically.

Comment: [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) implements Fragments better than the support library.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a tabhost for that:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html